# Database Query and Optimization - HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

depending on my scenario, can any one help me get my result through single query ? My scenario goes like this.

I have four tables, lets say HouseHold, HouseSurvey, HouseDailyExpense and CommodityList.

HouseSurvey has many HouseHold, HouseDailyExpense has many HouseSurvey and CommodityList.

What I want to achieve is sum of houseDailyExpense.expense of each CommodityList for each HouseHold.

Is this possible to achieve through one HQL query as its been more than four hours I have been trying and could not conclude through a sound solution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post something that you have tried?  It's in your best interest.

Comment: I have tried using joins, group by but all I could end up is either of following result.

Each HouseHold and sum of expense in HouseDailyExpense for Each HouseHold. ---
Each COmmodityList and sum of expense in HouseDailyExpense for each CommodityList. ---

But What I want is for each HouseHold, sum of all expense of all CommodityList

I hope its not confusing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select hh, cl, sum(hde.expense) from HouseDailyExpense hde join hde.houseSurveys as hs join hde.commodityLists as cl join hs.houseHolds as hh
group by hh, cl
```